# Export Resharper code style settings into Editor.Config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, editorconfig

I am trying to create a single place for code-style and formatting rules for our solution.

We are currently using Resharper, which stores this info in the `{slnName}.dotSettings` file. However, some developers don't want to use Resharper due to its performance issues. So they don't get these rules and warnings.

EditorConfig seemed like a suitable replacement, but I wanted to translate the ReSharper rules (where possible) into editor config rules and also include all the ReSharper specific rules so that those who do use ReSharper get the extra rules too, and they are all stored in one place (One source of truth!).

Anyway, trying to grasp what the `.dotSettings` file is doing has been unfruitful, and I know that Resharper will read in editor config files, so I'd like it to export it too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Resharper 2019.1 you can now 'Export settings to .editorconfig'. The option lives in Resharper -> Tools.

This will export the standard editor config options, the Visual Studio specific config options and the resharper specific configs. Very useful!

Answer (score 2):

In Reshaper 2019.3, this option is found in "**Resharper Options | Code Editing | General Formatter Style**"

[image]

As described here -> https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/03/28/export-editorconfig-code-style-optimize-references-sdk-projects-resharper-2019-1-eap-updates/